# Handling external authentication with routing.yml

Tags: 8, routes

I am building a new page (general use of "page", not literally referring to the node type) in my Drupal site that should only be accessible to members that have a certain permission. I have defined the routing for this in `mymodule.routing.yml` as follows:

```
mymodule.connector:
  path: '/mymodule/connector'
  defaults:
    _controller: \Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MymoduleConnectorController::content
  requirements:
    _permission: 'view mymodule entity'
```

This so far is working nicely, my accounts with this permission are able to view the content.

I also need `/mymodule/connector` to be accessible via an ajax request from a web view app that I made, which uses the same login credentials as my Drupal site, so essentially I need external authentication to work. I have tried to accomplish it by adding basic auth to my routing as explained [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/authentication-api):

```
mymodule.connector:
  path: '/mymodule/connector'
  defaults:
    _controller: \Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MymoduleConnectorController::content
  requirements:
    _permission: 'view mymodule entity'
  options:
    _auth: ['basic_auth']
```

However, when testing with Postman, using Basic Auth with my user credentials, this is a 403 error.

Is something wrong with my routing? I am not sure what else it could be as I am not very experienced with authentication.

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe I missed this. I simply had to go to /admin/modules and enable these:

[image]

Comment: You probably don't need hal module unless you're expecting to use application/json+hal content-type in your HTTP response.

Answer (score 2):

Thank for putting this up. I have been spending hours trying to get key_auth to work with a custom endpoint in one of my contrib modules, and what I was missing was the options key:

```
spectra.post_api:
  path: '/spectra/post'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Spectra POST API'
    _controller: '\Drupal\spectra\Controller\SpectraController::post_api'
  methods: [POST]
  options:
      _auth: ['key_auth', 'cookie']
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access spectra post api'
```

Just to expand on your solution, the auth array can include multiple parameters, and in my case, I did not need RESTful Web Services or any of the listed modules. However, HTTP Basic Auth might need them.